# Lions concentration lemma

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations

If for every $y\in\mathbb{R}^N$,  $$\int_{y+B_R}|w_n|^2dx \rightarrow 0 ,$$ as $n\rightarrow \infty$, where $R>0$ is some number and $B_R$ denotes the ball of radius $R$ at center origin; then can I say that  $\displaystyle\sup_{y\in \mathbb{R}^N}\int_{y+B_R}|w_n|^2dx\rightarrow 0$ as $n\rightarrow \infty$ ?

Comment: What is $w_n$? Simple a square integrable function?

Comment: $w_n$s are a sequence of functions such that $||w_n||_{L^2(\mathbb{R}^N)}=1$. Thus there exists a subsequence which weakly converges to $w$, say. Further $w_n$ satisfies that $\forall\epsilon>0$, $\exists y_n(\epsilon)$ such that $\int_{y_n+B_R}|w_n|^2\geq 1-\epsilon$ for some $R>0$. Define $\tilde{w_n}(.)=w_n(.+y_n)$. Now I can see that for a subsequence $\tilde{w_n}\rightarrow \tilde{w}$ strongly in $L^2(B_R)$. How do we see the same convergence in $L^2(\mathbb{R}^N)$?.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. Consider $h$ a unit vector and $w_0$ square-summable function with support $\subseteq B_R$.

Then, $w_n(x):=w_1(x-5nRh)$ is a counterexample. For all $y\in\Bbb R^n$ there is a sufficiently large $n_y$ such that $\operatorname{supp}w_n\cap(y+B_R)=\emptyset$ for all $n\ge n_y$.

However, $$\sup_{y\in\Bbb R^n}\lVert w_n\cdot 1_{y+B_R}\rVert^2=\lVert w_n\cdot1_{5nRh+B_R}\rVert^2=\lVert w_0\rVert^2$$